# Sending message to a specified usb keyboard when multiple keyboards are attached to usb ports

Tags: java, port

I have developed simple application that makes the keyboard act as an output device, it sends commands to the keyboard to turn on the caps lock LED. Now the problem is when two or more keyboards are connected, the command is broadcasted to all of them, and all the caps lock LED's in all keyboards are turned on. Is there a way i can use to send a message to a particular keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the serial port such as COM1, COM2 and then send data to specific keyboard.

```
 portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
 while (portList.hasMoreElements())
 {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
               if (portId.getName().equals("COM2")) {
}
```